# How to use tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession to restore only certain variables

Tags: tensorflow

**How does one tell a tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession to restore only a subset of the variables, and perform intialization on the rest?**

Starting with the cifar10 tutorial ..
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_train.py

.. I created lists of the variables to restore and initialize, and specified them using a Scaffold that I pass to the MonitoredTrainingSession:

```
  restoration_saver = Saver(var_list=restore_vars)
  restoration_scaffold = Scaffold(init_op=variables_initializer(init_vars),
                                  ready_op=constant([]),
                                  saver=restoration_saver)
```

but this gives the following error:

> RuntimeError: Init operations did not make model ready for local_init.  Init op: group_deps, init fn: None, error: Variables not initialized: conv2a/T, conv2b/T, [...]

.. where the uninitialized variables listed in the error message are the variables in my "init_vars" list.

The exception is raised by SessionManager.prepare_session(). The source code for that method seems to indicate that if the session is restored from a checkpoint, then the init_op is not run. So it looks like you can either have restored variables or initialized variables, but not both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK so as I suspected, I got what I wanted by implementing a new RefinementSessionManager class based on the existing tf.training.SessionManager. The two classes are almost identical, except I modified the prepare_session method to call the init_op regardless of whether the model was loaded from a checkpoint.

This allows me to load a list of variables from the checkpoint and initialize the remaining variables in the init_op.

My prepare_session method is this:

```
  def prepare_session(self, master, init_op=None, saver=None,
                  checkpoint_dir=None, wait_for_checkpoint=False,
                  max_wait_secs=7200, config=None, init_feed_dict=None,
                  init_fn=None):

    sess, is_loaded_from_checkpoint = self._restore_checkpoint(
    master,
    saver,
    checkpoint_dir=checkpoint_dir,
    wait_for_checkpoint=wait_for_checkpoint,
    max_wait_secs=max_wait_secs,
    config=config)

    # [removed] if not is_loaded_from_checkpoint:
    # we still want to run any supplied initialization on models that
    # were loaded from checkpoint.

    if not is_loaded_from_checkpoint and init_op is None and not init_fn and self._local_init_op is None:
      raise RuntimeError("Model is not initialized and no init_op or "
                     "init_fn or local_init_op was given")
    if init_op is not None:
      sess.run(init_op, feed_dict=init_feed_dict)
    if init_fn:
      init_fn(sess)

    # [...]
```

Hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: Just as a warning for future travelers, it seems if you don't feed an init op, this may re-initialize your restored variables leaving your model useless.  You can fix this by feeding a no-op.

Answer (score 2):

The hint from @avital works, to be more complete: pass a scaffolding object into `MonitoredTrainingSession` with a `local_init_op` **and** a `ready_for_local_init_op`. Like so:

```
model_ready_for_local_init_op = tf.report_uninitialized_variables(
            var_list=var_list)
model_init_tmp_vars = tf.variables_initializer(var_list)
scaffold = tf.train.Scaffold(saver=model_saver,
               local_init_op = model_init_tmp_vars,
               ready_for_local_init_op = model_ready_for_local_init_op)
with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(...,
                scaffold=scaffold,
                ...) as mon_sess:
   ...
```

Comment: I don't get it. Arent you initializing the model variables twice if you specify them as local_init_op. Shouldn't that be the other variables which are not saved in the model?

Comment: First I don't think it's a big problem to initialize variables twice, second you choose what variables are in your `var_list`. This question is about restoring some of your variables and initialize others than may be present in your model anyways. Bu maybe I don't get your question right?

Comment: What happens if I restore a variable and then initialize it? Wouldn't the restored state be overwritten then? Because `var_list` only includes the variables I am saving right? The way I understand is that the `model_ready_for_local_init_op` lets me know when all the variables in `var_list` are initialized (restored from the model) ie. returns an empty list and then I can go on and initialize the other variables which are not stored (ie. `model_init_tmp_vars`)?

Comment: From the documentation of Scaffold: `ready_for_local_init_op: Optional op to verify that the global variables
        are initialized and local_init_op can be run. Must return an empty
        1D string tensor when the global variables are initialized, or a
        non-empty 1D string tensor listing the names of the non-initialized
        global variables.` So how does it make sense to use the same var_list for `ready_for_local_init_op` and `local_init_op`?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with the `local_init_op` argument, which does get run after loading from a checkpoint.

Answer (score 1):

`Scaffold` 's [arguments](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py#L107) contain following:

- init_op
- ready_op
- local_init_op
- ready_for_local_init_op

`init_op` will only be called when we **do NOT** restore from a checkpoint.

```python
if not is_loaded_from_checkpoint:
  if init_op is None and not init_fn and self._local_init_op is None:
    raise RuntimeError("Model is not initialized and no init_op or "
                   "init_fn or local_init_op was given")
  if init_op is not None:
    sess.run(init_op, feed_dict=init_feed_dict)
  if init_fn:
    init_fn(sess)
```

So actually `init_op` can not help here. If you can write a new `SessionManager`, you can follow @user550701. We can also use `local_init_op`, but it may be a little tricky in distributed situations.

`Scaffold` will generate default `init_op` and `local_init_op` for us: [Details here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py#L177)

- init_op: will initialize `tf.global_variables`
- local_init_op: will initialize `tf.local_variables`

We should initialize our variables and do not break the default mechanism at the same time.

#### One worker situation

You can create `local_init_op` like this:

```
target_collection = [] # Put your target tensors here
collection = tf.local_variables() + target_collection
local_init_op = tf.variables_initializer(collection)
ready_for_local_init_op = tf.report_uninitialized_variables(collection)
```

#### Distributed situation

We should take care of duplicate initialization of our `target_collection` because `local_init_op` will be called multiple times on multiple workers. If variables are local, it makes no difference. If they are global variables, we should make sure that it only be initialized once. To solve the duplicate problem, we can manipulate the `collection` variable. On chief worker, it includes both local variables and our `target_collection`. While for non-chief worker, we only put local variables into it.

```
if is_chief:
   collection = tf.local_variables() + target_collection
else:
   collection = tf.local_variables()
```

All in all, it is a little tricky, but we do not have to hack into tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered the same problem, and my solution is

```
checkpoint_restore_dir_for_monitered_session = None
scaffold = None
if params.restore:
    checkpoint_restore_dir_for_monitered_session = checkpoint_save_dir

    restore_exclude_name_list = params.restore_exclude_name_list
    if len(restore_exclude_name_list) != 0:
        variables_to_restore, variables_dont_restore = get_restore_var_list(restore_exclude_name_list)
        saver_for_restore = tf.train.Saver(var_list=variables_to_restore, name='saver_for_restore')
        ready_for_local_init_op = tf.report_uninitialized_variables(variables_to_restore.values())

        local_init_op = tf.group([
            tf.initializers.local_variables(),
            tf.initializers.variables(variables_dont_restore)
            ])

        scaffold = tf.train.Scaffold(saver=saver_for_restore,
                ready_for_local_init_op=ready_for_local_init_op,
                local_init_op=local_init_op)

with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(
        checkpoint_dir=checkpoint_restore_dir_for_monitered_session, 
        save_checkpoint_secs=None,  # don't save ckpt
        hooks=train_hooks,
        config=config,
        scaffold=scaffold,
        summary_dir=params.log_dir) as sess:
    pass
```

In this code fragment, `get_restore_var_list` gets `variables_to_restore` and `variables_dont_restore`.
`saver_for_restore` only restores variables in `variables_to_restore`, which are checked and pass through by `ready_for_local_init_op` after that.
Then `local_init_op` will run, which initialize `local_variables()` and `variables_dont_restore` (maybe `tf.variance_scaling_initializer`...).