# In tensorflow,when graph is modified, how to use "MonitoredTrainingSession" to restore only part of checkpoint?

Tags: tensorflow

My purpose is simple and clear: After the graph is partially modified, how to restore the unchanged variables/parameters from previous log's checkpoint file?(Better using MonitoredTrainingSession)

I make a test on the code from here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/resnet

In resnet_model.py,line 116-118,the original code(or graph) is:

```
with tf.variable_scope('logit'):
    logits = self._fully_connected(x, self.hps.num_classes)
    self.predictions = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
with tf.variable_scope('costs'):
    xent = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    logits=logits, labels=self.labels)
    self.cost = tf.reduce_mean(xent, name='xent')
    self.cost += self._decay()
```

after the first training, I obtain checkpoint files.
Then I modified the code to:

```
with tf.variable_scope('logit_modified'):
    logits_modified = self._fully_connected('fc_1',x, 48)
    #self.predictions = tf.nn.softmax(logits)    
with tf.variable_scope('logit_2'):
    logits_2 = self._fully_connected('fc_2', logits_modified, 
    self.hps.num_classes)
    self.predictions = tf.nn.softmax(logits_2)
with tf.variable_scope('costs'):
    xent = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    logits=logits_2, labels=self.labels)
    self.cost = tf.reduce_mean(xent, name='xent')
    self.cost += self._decay()
```

Then I try to use the latested API tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession to restore the checkpoint obtained in the first training. I have tried mutiple methods to do this, but none of them works.

Try 1:
If I don't use scaffold in MonitoredTrainingSession:

```
with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(
    checkpoint_dir=FLAGS.log_root,
    #scaffold=scaffold,
    hooks=[logging_hook, _LearningRateSetterHook()],
    chief_only_hooks=[summary_hook],
    save_checkpoint_secs = 600,
    # Since we provide a SummarySaverHook, we need to disable default
    # SummarySaverHook. To do that we set save_summaries_steps to 0.
    save_summaries_steps=None,
    save_summaries_secs=None,
    config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True),
    stop_grace_period_secs=120,
    log_step_count_steps=100) as mon_sess:
while not mon_sess.should_stop():
    mon_sess.run(_train_op)
```

The error messages are:

> 2017-12-29 10:33:30.699061: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Not found: Key logit_modified/fc_1/biases/Momentum not found in checkpoint
>   ...

While It seems that the session trys to restore according to the modified graph but not the variables that exists both in the new graph and the previous checkpoint file(in other words all layers exclude the final 2).

Try 2: 
Inspired by the transfer learning code using tf.train.Supervisor here:
https://github.com/kwotsin/transfer_learning_tutorial/blob/master/train_flowers.py, from line 251.

First I modified the code in resnet_model.py, add this line:

```
self.variables_to_restore = tf.contrib.framework.get_variables_to_restore(
exclude=["logit_modified", "logit_2"])
```

Then the scaffold in MonitoredTrainingSession is changed to:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
def restore_fn(sess):
    return saver.restore(sess, FLAGS.log_root)
scaffold = tf.train.Scaffold(saver=saver, init_fn = restore_fn)
```

Unfortunately the followiing error message was shown:

> RuntimeError: Init operations did not make model ready for local_init.  Init op: group_deps, init fn:  at 0x7f0ec26f4320>, error: Variables not initialized: logit_modified/fc_1/DW, ...

Seems like the last 2 layers are not restored properly, so that the rest layers are not restored.

Try 3:
I also tried methods that list here:[How to use tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession to restore only certain variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336553/how-to-use-tf-train-monitoredtrainingsession-to-restore-only-certain-variables), but none of them works.

I know there are others methods to restore such as the code in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/6fb14a790c283a922119b19632e3f7b8e5c0a729/research/inception/inception/inception_model.py, but they are nested and not general enough to be applied to other models easily. This is the reason why I want to use "MonitoredTrainingSession".

So how to use "MonitoredTrainingSession" to restore only part of checkpoint in tensorflow?

Comment: sorry that the error message always have indent problem on StackOverflow. The main idea of error message were illustrated in the Question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, finally I figure it out.

After reading the monitored_session.py here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4806cb0646bd21f713722bd97c0d0262c575f7e0/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py, I've found the key(and very tricky) point is to change to a **new empty checkpoint directory**, so that the MonitoredTrainingSession will not ignore init_op or init_fn.
Then you can use the following code to build your init_fn(in order to restore checkpoint) as well as scaffold:

```
variables_to_restore = tf.contrib.framework.get_variables_to_restore(
    exclude=['XXX'])    
init_assign_op, init_feed_dict = tf.contrib.framework.assign_from_checkpoint(
    ckpt.model_checkpoint_path, variables_to_restore)
def InitAssignFn(scaffold,sess):
    sess.run(init_assign_op, init_feed_dict)

scaffold = tf.train.Scaffold(saver=tf.train.Saver(), init_fn=InitAssignFn)
```

Remember the **ckpt.model_checkpoint_path** above is your old checkpoint path with pretrained files in it. The **new empty checkpoint directory** which I have mentioned above means the parameter "checkpoint_dir" of MonitoredTrainingSession here:

```
with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(
    checkpoint_dir=FLAGS.log_root_2,...) as mon_sess:
while not mon_sess.should_stop():
    mon_sess.run(_train_op)
```

The first paragraph of code modified by me derives from learning.py in tf.slim, from line 134:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py

Plus:
Thanks this Q&A for inspiration, though the solution is a little bit different:
[What's the recommend way of restoring only parts model in distributed tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43883062/whats-the-recommend-way-of-restoring-only-parts-model-in-distributed-tensorflow)

Comment: I found that it is important to use a new saver for loading pretrained model as in your code. When I used the same Saver for loading pretrained model and saving checkpoints, the saver will only save the ops that appear in the loaded checkpoint and ignore the newly-added ops, even without specifying variables_to_restore.